# Google calendar API time format

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, datetime-format

I was playing with [Google calendar's API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/calendar/v3/) and managed to get the events list from my calendar. And i managed to insert some events into the calendar from API explorer. But im confused with the time property.

When i inserted an event from explorer, i wanted event time to be from 09:30 to 10:30. So i put as following:

```
{
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T10:30:00.0z"
 },
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-12T09:30:00.0z"
 }
}
```

Insertion was successful. But when i checked the calendar, its showing that event's time as 03:30-04:30. Date is correct. Any idea where i went wrong?

---

And when i retrieved the same event using the explorer, i got this:

```
"start": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-11T03:30:00-06:00"
},
"end": {
  "dateTime": "2012-07-11T04:30:00-06:00"
}
```

Please notice the time now => 03:30:00-06:00 and 04:30:00-06:00. What is that -06:00?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are inserting the event, you are doing that in the UTC timezone (notice the 'z' at the end of the value), but your calendar is probably in a different timezone. The -06:00 indicates the UTC-6 timezone which should be Central Standard Time.